# Git push heroku error

Tags: ruby, heroku

I'm trying push the application to Heroku: 'git push heroku master', but getting error:

> c:\Sites\rails_project\first_app>git push heroku master
>   Counting objects: 63, done.
>   Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
>   Compressing objects: 100% (49/49), done.
>   Writing objects: 100% (63/63), 25.95 KiB, done.
>   Total 63 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
>
> -----> Heroku receiving push
>   -----> Ruby/Rails app detected
>   -----> Installing dependencies using Bundler version 1.2.0.pre
>          Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle
>   -binstubs bin/
>          Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
>          Installing rake (0.9.2.2)
>          Installing i18n (0.6.0)
>          Installing multi_json (1.3.6)
>          Installing activesupport (3.2.1)
>          Installing builder (3.0.0)
>          Installing activemodel (3.2.1)
>          Installing erubis (2.7.0)
>          Installing journey (1.0.4)
>          Installing rack (1.4.1)
>          Installing rack-cache (1.2)
>          Installing rack-test (0.6.1)
>          Installing hike (1.2.1)
>          Installing tilt (1.3.3)
>          Installing sprockets (2.1.3)
>          Installing actionpack (3.2.1)
>          Installing mime-types (1.19)
>          Installing polyglot (0.3.3)
>          Installing treetop (1.4.10)
>          Installing mail (2.4.4)
>          Installing actionmailer (3.2.1)
>          Installing arel (3.0.2)
>          Installing tzinfo (0.3.33)
>          Installing activerecord (3.2.1)
>          Installing activeresource (3.2.1)
>          Using bundler (1.2.0.pre)
>          Installing coffee-script-source (1.3.3)
>          Installing execjs (1.4.0)
>          Installing coffee-script (2.2.0)
>          Installing rack-ssl (1.3.2)
>          Installing json (1.7.3) with native extensions
>          Installing rdoc (3.12)
>          Installing thor (0.14.6)
>          Installing railties (3.2.1)
>          Installing coffee-rails (3.2.2)
>          Installing jquery-rails (2.0.2)
>          Installing rails (3.2.1)
>          Installing sass (3.1.20)
>          Installing sass-rails (3.2.5)
>          Installing sqlite3 (1.3.3) with native extensions
>          Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native
>   tension.
>          /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb
>          checking for sqlite3.h... no
>          sqlite3.h is missing. Try 'port install sqlite3 +universal'
>          or 'yum install sqlite3-devel' and check your shared library search pat
>   (the
>          location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
>          *** extconf.rb failed ***
>          Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
>          necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
>          details.  You may need configuration options.
>          Provided configuration options:
>          --with-opt-dir
>          --without-opt-dir
>          --with-opt-include
>          --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
>          --with-opt-lib
>          --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
>          --with-make-prog
>          --without-make-prog
>          --srcdir=.
>          --curdir
>          --ruby=/usr/local/bin/ruby
>          --with-sqlite3-dir
>          --without-sqlite3-dir
>          --with-sqlite3-include
>          --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
>          --with-sqlite3-lib
>          --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/lib
>          Gem files will remain installed in /tmp/build_3kebgpytmvg9c/vendor/bund
>   /ruby/1.9.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.3 for inspection.
>          Results logged to /tmp/build_3kebgpytmvg9c/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gem
>   sqlite3-1.3.3/ext/sqlite3/gem_make.out
>          An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.3), and Bundler cannot
>   ntinue.
>          **Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.3'` succeeds before bundlin
>   
>
>    !
>
>    !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.**
>
>    !
>    !     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Ruby/rails app
>   
>   To git@heroku.com:electric-mountain-4030.git
>    ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
>   error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:electric-mountain-4030.git'

I make install sqllite3, but:

> c:\Sites\rails_project\first_app>gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3
>   Fetching: sqlite3-1.3.3-x86-mingw32.gem (100%)
>
> You've installed the binary version of sqlite3.
>     It was built using SQLite3 version 3.7.3.
>     It's recommended to use the exact same version to avoid po
>
> At the time of building this gem, the necessary DLL files
>     in the following download:
>
> http://www.sqlite.org/sqlitedll-3_7_3.zip
>
> You can put the sqlite3.dll available in this package in y
>     directory, for example C:\Ruby\bin
>
> ============================================================
>   
>   Successfully installed sqlite3-1.3.3-x86-mingw32
>   1 gem installed
>   Installing ri documentation for sqlite3-1.3.3-x86-mingw32...
>   Installing RDoc documentation for sqlite3-1.3.3-x86-mingw32.
>   ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
>       You don't have write permissions into the js directory.

thank

Answer (score 5):

Heroku uses PostgreSQL databases not SQLite. So you have to do something like this in your Gemfile:

```
group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end
```

That way you can use SQLite in development and PostgreSQL in production (on Heroku). With these settings Heroku won't try to install the SQLite gem, which is causing the error.